# Display the page title in header - Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, header

I need to caption or rather add proper site title to the header image.

What I need is to add page title to header image in normal page while in front page there will be no page title shown (Because there's SVG logo instead). Here's code I took from "content-header.php":

```
// Display the image and text
    ?>
    <header class="content-header-image">
        <div class="<?php echo $image_class; ?>" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image_url; ?>')">
            <div class="<?php echo $overlay_class; ?>">
            <h1 class="header-image-title"><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
            <?php if ( $subtitle ) echo '<h2 class="header-image-caption">' . $subtitle . '</h2>'; ?>
            <?php if ( $description ) echo '<p class="header-image-description">' . $description . '</p>'; ?> 

            <?php               
            // Only for static home page, show a scroll down icon
            if ( is_front_page() ) {
                echo '<div class="spacer"></div>';
                echo '<a href="#pagetop" class="scroll-down smoothscroll"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></a>';
            }
            ?>

            </div><!-- .cover-image-overlay or .section-image-overlay -->
        </div><!-- .cover-image or .section-image -->
    </header><!-- content-header-image -->
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use 
`<h1><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></h1>`

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to use your

```
    if(is_front_page()){ what you have }
      else{ echo 'other content for other pages';}
```

to conditionally show the logo on the home page and other content on all other pages